# Using anchor tag to link to an external URL in Java

Tags: java, http, telegram

I'm trying to send a Telegram message from an Android app. I want that message to contain a hyperlink so I used `parse_mode=html` param but I have a problem with the anchor tag. It seems that java is treating my URL as a local path.

This is the code:

```
String location = "http://www.google.com";
urlString = String.format("https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot_token>/sendMessage?chat_id=<chat_id>&parse_mode=html&text=<a href=%s>Location</a>", location);

URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String inputLine = "";
while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(inputLine);
}
```

And this is the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
    https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot_token>/sendMessage?chat_id=<chat_id>&parse_mode=html&text=<a href=http://google.com>Location</a>
```

How should I write this message so the href link will be treated as an external URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `java.io.FileNotFoundException` doesn't mean that it is treated as a local path.

It is [HTTP 404 File Not Found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404). And it is the response from the server for your HTTP Request.

It seems that at first **to provide proper `<bot_token>` and `<chat_id>`** is needed. And second, you should **urlencode** that String before instantiating a `URL` object with it.

```
String encodedUrlString = URLEncoder.encode(urlString, "UTF-8");
URL url = new URL(encodedUrlString);
```